# How to dynamically fill controls on a selection changed in a aspxgridview

Tags: callback, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a AspxGridView which is linked to a DataSource. Below the GridView there are some textBoxes which should be populated on a selection changed event. How can I achieve that? Maybe with a callback panel and the clientSide SelectionChanged to fires a custom callback or ... ? Or maybe the SelectionChange isn't the appropriate event? I can see that in the gridview there are Begin and EndCallback on the client sides but when are they actually executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:
1. Place your text boxes inside `ASPxCallbackPanel`
2. Set callback panel `ClientInstanceName` to e.g. `callbackPanel1`
3. On `ASPxGridView` client side selection changed event call [callbackPanel1.PerformCallback](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxCallbackPanelScriptsASPxClientCallbackPanel_PerformCallbacktopic)
4. Set text boxes values in [ASPxCallbackPanel.Callback](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxCallbackPanelASPxCallbackPanel_Callbacktopic) event handler

[The Concept of Callbacks](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18387.aspx) knowledge base article is mandatory reading.

Comment: okey and on PerformCallback how I can pass the keyfield(in my case the id)?

Comment: you can pass it as parameter of PerformCallback js method.

Answer (score 0):

Since your textboxes are outside the grid, it should be easy:

```
  void MyGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    MyTextBox.Text = "You selected something.";
  }
```

Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx

Comment: Okey but isn't there any way to force the aspxgridview to cause a callback on SelectionChange, and to populate the required fields on that callback ?

Comment: SecelctedIndexChanged generates a postback. I don't understand why you want custom callbacks since you use gridview and texboxes which are standard asp.net controls. As far as I understand you want to update some textboxes when the user selects an item in the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Selection/Selection.aspx) demo to learn more on how to achieve this task on the client side.